# an adverb or adjective?quickly and effectively or quick and effective

Tags: word-choice

To perform work together is quickly and effectively. ( Or "performing work together is quick and effective")

Comment: Generally we'd use the adjective forms in a sentence like this, but this is a very basic question and you might consider asking at [English Language Learners Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It mainly depends on if you are applying the words to nouns or verbs. (*I am working quickly and effectively* or *the work is quick and effective.*)